# jQuery Validator, reset password fields and messages

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery Validation plugin for form fields validation. Idea is that if any field on form submit is not valid password fields and their error messages reset, while other fields remain.
I've menage to reset password fields but I can't remove error messages.

Code's here: http://jsfiddle.net/2Z9jp/

If you enter invalid values for all fields and submit, password input fields will be empty, but their errors are still there. What I want is to remove error messages for password fields in this case.

It seems that highlight happens after invalidHandler and that that cause this issue.

Here's the code:

```
<form id="registerForm" class="regForms" method="post" action="/">

        <span>username: </span><input type="text" id="username" name="username" /><br />
        <span class="passwordHolder">
            <span>password: </span><input type="password" id="password1" name="password1" /><br />
        </span>
        <span class="passwordHolder">
            <span>confirm password: </span><input type="password" id="password2" name="password2" /><br />
        </span>

        <input type="submit" />
    </div>
</form>



$("#registerForm").validate({
    rules: {
        username: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6
        },
        password1: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6,
            maxlength: 256
        },
        password2: {
            required: true,
            equalTo: "#password1",
            minlength: 6,
            maxlength: 256
        }
    },

    messages: {
        username: {
            required: "required",
            minlength: "should be 6 or longer"
        },
        password1: {
            required: "required",
            minlength: "should be 6 or longer"
        },
        password2: {
            required: "required",
            minlength: "should be 6 or longer",
            equalTo: "should be the same as password"
        }
    },

    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
        $(':password').val('');
        $('.passwordHolder label.error').hide();
    }

});
```

Comment: It's marked as a required field, so it's always going to get flagged as `invalid` no matter what you try to do... that's what the plugin is supposed to do when a field fails validation.  And clicking `submit` twice brings back the other error message.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are absolutely right with your suggestion that highlight appears after invalidHandler.
I think you should use the errorPlacement method. The documentation can be found here:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

You can check for element of type password and omit the error placement in that case.

Additionaly some code:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if(!element.is(':password'))
              element.after(error);
   },
   debug:true
 })
```

Comment: I've tried errorPlacement, but with this I'll never get passwords validation messages and I just need to clear them on submit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `label.error` are added after `invalidHandler` call.

A fast workaround could be to use setTimeout

```
setTimeout(function() {
            $('.passwordHolder label.error').hide();
          },100);
```

Answer (score 0):

While submitting the form you can check like this:

```
$("#registerForm").submit(function(){
    if ($("#password1").valid() == true ) {
       alert('Ok');
    }
});
```